# Save image that is displayed in UIImage and categorize it

Tags: ios, uiimageview, save, categories

I want to save an image that is displayed in the `UIImage`.  However I want to **categorize it in genre** for example vegetables, meat, lettuce, etc.

I cannot find a way to do that.
What is the best and easiest way to do this?

Also I want to make the user select which category he wants to save using the picker controller to save. 
  Thank you! I really need help!!

**Update 2**
 
To check if it is saved I went further to construct a collection View controller and I get errors saying at the images part at the `[arrayCollectionImages addObject:image];` Can you explain me about this last piece of code. I also have an warning at arrayCollectionImages saying local declaration of arrayColectionImages hide instance variable. –

```
@interface CollectionViewController (){
    NSArray *arrayCollectionImages;
}


@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
        dispatch_queue_t searchQ = dispatch_queue_create("com.awesome", 0);
        dispatch_async(searchQ, ^{
            NSArray *arrayCollectionImages = [[NSArray alloc ]init];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *location=@"Hats";
            NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
            NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
            for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
                NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
                if(data)
                {   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                });
                    [arrayCollectionImages addObject:images];
                }
            }
        });

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReuseID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell collectionImageView]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayCollectionImages objectAtindex:indexPath.item]]];
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [arrayCollectionImages count];
}
@end
```

Comment: Save the image where? To the file? And what do you mean categorize it? What code do you have so far?

Comment: You can save each image to a separate folder in the sandbox of your app. The images wont be visible in Gallery and will be accessible only to your app. Do you want like this?

Comment: Lets move our discussion on chat

Comment: 1.As you are not using UIImagePickerController , you dont need to include -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    if(CFStringCompare((CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo){
        captureImage= (UIImage*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }
}
By the way, in header file is for declaration only. We cant put implementation code inside it.
2. You have used AVCapture to capture the image and capturedIamge is saved in captureImage variable. See my edits.

Comment: This is a huge step to use UICollectionView to fetch images and you are using GCD as well. I would encourage you to go slow as I feel you are a beginner in iOS. Simple step would be to NSLog directoryContent array. If it contains anything, than you have successfully saved the image, if it doesnot than you have to keep learning. I feel you have chosen a very wide topic for a beginner. I would encourage you to read Apple docs or a good book to start learning. Head First's iOS development book could be a start.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
 Set up a Picker Controller.
Here is the [official reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)
Here is a [tutorial.](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPickerView_Example)

Try to set it with all the genre values you want. You will learn about its delegate method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

that will return the genre selected.

**Step 2:**
Provide a save icon or a save button on each image. On click of that icon/button you should make your picker view appear and make user select any row and the image should be copied to a private variable or a property here, so as to refer it later in the delegate method.

**Step 3:** 
When user selects a row, this delegate method is called. Here we will create a new directory , if not already exists, according to the genre selected In UIPickerView. Then you should write your image to the path.

```
   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
            NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            //fetch Category Name from the array used to fill the Picker View 
            NSString *categoryName= [array objectAtIndex:row];
            NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:categoryName];
            NSFileManager *fileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc]init];
            [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:fPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:NO error:NO];

            UIImage *image= captureImage;
            NSData *data= UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            [data writeToFile:fPath atomically:NO];
}
```

**To retrieve images from a particular folder in your documents directory:**
Create a path to that folder first. This will depend on a particular genre. Let's say Genre1.

```
 // An array to save all images. You have to do this in some other way if selected images are big in size.
 // For that case I suggest retrieving of images only when you are showing them on screen. 
  NSArray *allImagesArray = [[NSArray alloc ]init];
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *location=@"Genre1";
  NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location]; 
  NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
  for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
   NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str]; 
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
      if(data)
      {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [allImagesArray addObject:image];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Where Do we put the step 2 code is it the View did load? How can I use the picker view to select where to save?? I don't really get step 3 aswell. I was able to do step 1

Comment: See my edits. In Step 2: you should write a saveAction and appear your PickerView,and save your image reference for further use.

Comment: I Updated my question can you look at it?  I am almost done.. but have few more problems.

Comment: Look at the Update. If you are stuck somewhere, don't hesitate to ask. Happy Coding..:)

Comment: Sorry to comment many times. I was able to clear off the warnings and I was able to hide the picker view but do I be needing a save button that takes what the picture to the indicating directory that the user has picked? I am at the last bit where the user can save but I can't do it. The user cannow pick which category they want to save to but I can't go further then that. where the user can ***SAVE***

Comment: When you click on any row of the UIPIckerView, its delegate method,  (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component, gets called automatically.
If it is not getting called that means you have not set the delegate property of UIPickerView.

To set it:: SaveTopicker.delegate = self;

Comment: I think show ing you in a video is better so check my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGxlrccBZq4).  I think I have don all of the codes rite and is this save? or am I missing something? I don't believe that this is saving the picture.

Comment: I wont be able to see the video now, I have to go back home and check.
But you can see whether you have managed to save the image or not. If you are testing on simulator, Open your app's sandbox following tehse steps: Finder -> Go to folder -> ~/library -> Application Support -> iPhone Simulator -> 6.1- > Applications -> "Find out your app" -> Documents

Comment: ok I would  wait,  I am really trying hard to get this working.

Comment: Did you see my edit on the above comment? Have you been able to find the images in Documents Directory of your app?

Comment: I am using a ios device.  I cannot use the simulator since I am using the camera.  sorry

Comment: Use the Code To retrieve images from a particular folder in your documents directory. NSLog the array. That will show you the name of the image saved if there is one. In place of "Genre1", give name of the Genre previously selected.
NSLog(@"%@", directoryContent);
If it logs any name  that means your save code is working.

Comment: It does not look like it is saved .  Can you look at the video when you go home? I think I have misunderstand you at someplace.

Comment: I did look at the video. It looks there is nothing happening when you are selecting the value in Picker View. I would suggest you to use debug and see whether that method is getting called or not.

Comment: I did not select it I just turned the wheel and hit close....Is this ok? or do I need another save button after choosing the genre in the picker.  For example take photo, tap save, shows the picker so I choose the genre and I hit save.  In the video I was taking photo, tap save, automatically shows the picker and choose genre,and hit close picker.

Comment: There is no tap event for UIPickerView. When you are sliding on the wheel and stops at one point, then UIPickerView's delegate method is called. In the video you are doing fine. i just want to know whether that delegate is getting called or not. if not than you have to set the delegate property like this:SaveTopicker.delegate = self;

Comment: Can you look at my question again?